# Finding $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\varepsilon}^{\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\varepsilon}^{\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}dx$$

Okay this seems weird to me-- couldn't i just write down the answer 0 because $\int_{0}^{0} f(x)dx=0$? (The answer is $-1$ btw)
There was even a hint for the question: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-x^2}-1}{x^2}$ may be useful.

Am I supposed to go  $$\displaystyle \int_{\varepsilon}^{0}\frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2}dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}}\frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2}dx\,\,\,?$$ And I couldn't even go L'Hospital with that.....
Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks!

Of course, it would be nice if the answer was simply 0!

Answer (score 6):

The value of this limit is $-1$. $$\int_{\epsilon} ^{\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}} \frac {e^{-x^2}} {x^{2}}dx =\int_{\epsilon} ^{\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}} \frac {e^{-x^2}-1} {x^{2}}dx +\int_{\epsilon} ^{\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}} \frac 1 {x^{2}} dx$$. You can easily evaluate the limit of  second term by evaluating the integral explicitly. For the first term observe that $\frac {e^{-x^2}-1} {x^{2}}$ is bounded function. For any bounded function $f$ we have $$\left|\int_{\epsilon} ^{\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}} f(x)dx\right| \leq M\left(\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}-\epsilon\right) \to 0$$ where $M$ is a bound for $|f|$.

For boundedness of $\frac {e^{-x^2}-1} {x^{2}}$ note that it is continuous on $(0,1]$ and it has  a finite limit, namely $0$, at $0$. (Use series expansion for the limit. You can also use L'Hopital's Rule if you prefer).

Comment: Nice and simple approach. I think the idea is evident if one tries to get a Taylor expansion of integrand and notices that the first term matters (others leading to analytic around $0$).

Comment: This means that $\int_{a}^{a}f(x)dx$ Is not an indeterminate form? Why? It should be determinate, shouldn't it? I mean, Its not $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $1^{\infty}$ or $\infty-\infty$ or any of the sort. Well, I'm pretty sure you could just say $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\epsilon}^{\epsilon^2}xdx$ is equal to 0 without evaluating it-- what's the catch?

Comment: @LeeLaindingold That argument is valid for the intergal of $x$  because  $f(x)=x$ has no singularity at $0$ .But in our case the integrand has  a singularity at $0$. It is not even bounded as $x \to 0$. So we cannot immediately say that the limit is $0$ even though the limits of the integral both tend to $0$. . In  fact the given limit is $-1$,  not $0$.

Comment: @LeeLaindingold: if you want to visualize (with some loss of rigor) then imagine a rectangular strip whose width is decreasing to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ but at the same time the height is also increasing to $\infty $ and the process of finding its area is somewhat comparable to the form $0\times \infty$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh that's an interesting explanation! Would that suggest that $\int_{x}^{0}f(x)dx$ is also not neccesarily equal to 0 when $x\to 0$? Because I often see limit problems of the sort $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x^2}\frac{\sin u}{u}du}{\sin x^2}$, I usually do it by L'Hospital's rule, so does that mean that I, in fact, cannot use LH?

Comment: @LeeLaindingold: well if the integrand is bounded (height of rectangle does not exceed a fixed number) then the integral does tend to $0$ as the length of interval of integration tends to $0$ (and this applies to the integral in your last comment as $(\sin x) /x$ is bounded).

Answer (score 2):

Consider

$I:=\displaystyle{\int_{\epsilon/(\epsilon+1)}^{e}} \dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}dx, \epsilon >0$;

$e^{-(\epsilon/(1+\epsilon))^2} \displaystyle{\int_{\epsilon/(\epsilon+1)}^{\epsilon}}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}dx> I >$

$e^{-\epsilon^{2}}\displaystyle{\int_{\epsilon/(1+\epsilon)}^{\epsilon}}\dfrac{1}{x^2}dx;$

Calculate the above integral and take the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}$ (Squeeze Theorem).

Similarly for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{-}.$

Comment: You need to add a minus sign in exponent and assume $\epsilon \to 0^+$. Rest appears fine.

Comment: Hope it looks better now.Thanks!

Comment: @PeterSzilas this is..... what rule is this?

Comment: Lee. Second line: $e^{-(\epsilon/(1+\epsilon))^2}/x^2 \ge   e^{-x^2} /x^2$ in the interval of integration. You integrate two functions, say $F$ and $G$, where you have $F \ge G$. What can you say about their  integrals?  Is this your question?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\varepsilon\to 0$, the domain of integration is very small ($\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\sim \varepsilon-\varepsilon^2$). Using series
$$\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}-1+\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$\int\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}dx\sim -\frac{1}{x}-x+\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$

Using the bounds,
$$I=\left(\frac{\varepsilon ^3}{6 (\varepsilon +1)^3}-\frac{\varepsilon }{\varepsilon
   +1}-\frac{\varepsilon +1}{\varepsilon } \right) -\left(\frac{\varepsilon ^3}{6}-\varepsilon -\frac{1}{\varepsilon } \right)$$

Using Taylor
$$I=-1+\varepsilon ^2-\varepsilon ^3+O\left(\varepsilon ^4\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you like this method or not. By the MVT for definite integrals, there is $\xi\in(\varepsilon,\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon})$ such that
$$\int_{\varepsilon}^{\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}dx=e^{-\xi^2}\int_{\varepsilon}^{\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=e^{-\xi^2}(-\frac{1}{x})\bigg|_{\varepsilon}^{\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}}=-e^{-\xi^2}$$
and hence
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\varepsilon}^{\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}dx=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}(-e^{-\xi^2})=-1.$$